# thorough guide for profiling racket code

Tags: profiling, racket

Did some googling ("racket profiling", "racket measure performance"), but didn't find any and there are *no examples* in the docs. Even did google "profile" search on `htdp` - no luck. `(profile (f ...))` output isn't that obvious other than for small snippets.

Ideally I want something like python's `python -m cProfile` usage examples.

Comment: Some people might want to close this as a tool/library request, but since so much of the Racket development environment is bundled together, this is a really a question about "how do I use racket's profiler?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When I search for "Python profiling", both DuckDuckGo and Google give this as the top result: [26.4. The Python Profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

(Although I scanned it quickly, it seems like more of a reference than a "thorough usage guide" with examples. So if you had something else in mind, perhaps you could please link to that?)

The equivalent Racket documentation would be: [Profile: Statistical Profiler](http://docs.racket-lang.org/profile/index.html).

A usage example:

```
#lang racket
(require profile)
(profile-thunk (thunk (function-to-profile arg0 arg1) ))
```

Here `(thunk e)` is just a convenience for `(lambda () e)`.

---

Bigger example:

```
#lang racket

(module mod racket
  (provide f)
  (define (f)
    (for/list ([i 10000])
      i)))

(require (prefix-in mod: 'mod))

(define (f)
  (for ([i 10000])
    (mod:f)))

(require profile)
(profile-thunk f)
```

For me this outputs:

```
Profiling results
-----------------
  Total cpu time observed: 5666ms (out of 5753ms)
  Number of samples taken: 105 (once every 54ms)

========================================================
                               Caller
Idx   Total        Self      Name+src             Local%
      ms(pct)      ms(pct)     Callee
========================================================
[1] 5666(100.0%)    0(0.0%)  [running body] /tmp/profile.rkt:##f
                               profile-thunk14 [2]100.0%
--------------------------------------------------------
                               [running body] [1] 100.0%
[2] 5666(100.0%)    0(0.0%)  profile-thunk14 ...e-pkgs/profile-lib/main.rkt:9:0
                               run [3]            100.0%
--------------------------------------------------------
                               profile-thunk14 [2]100.0%
[3] 5666(100.0%)    0(0.0%)  run ...pkgs/profile-pkgs/profile-lib/main.rkt:31:2
                               for-loop [4]       100.0%
--------------------------------------------------------
                               run [3]            100.0%
[4] 5666(100.0%) 1630(28.8%) for-loop /tmp/profile.rkt:12:2
                               f [5]               71.2%
--------------------------------------------------------
                               for-loop [4]       100.0%
[5] 4036(71.2%)  1786(31.5%) f /tmp/profile.rkt:5:2
                               for-loop [6]        55.8%
--------------------------------------------------------
                               f [5]              100.0%
[6] 2250(39.7%)  2250(39.7%) for-loop /tmp/profile.rkt:6:4
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that it does show line numbers, so that even though there are two functions named `f`, it is possible to see which one -- and in fact which part of each one.

---

Also I strongly recommend the [Optimization Coach](https://github.com/stamourv/optimization-coach) package. Although this will give you different insights than the traditional profiler, it also gives you specific suggestions how to change the code to likely be faster. As a by-product it teaches you how to write it that way in the first place.

Comment: Equivalent Racket documentation has ZERO(!) examples. Really surprising. And profiling just expressions is not enough (read: no line number). Ok for toying, not ok for a bit larger code imo. Especially if my inner functions have the same names.

As for thoroughness.. I see lots of blog posts for "python profiling". Nothing for racket again. Thanks for "opt. coach" will definitely take a look.

Comment: Actually it does show line numbers. Please see my updated answer with slightly bigger example, and the output.

Comment: p.s. Although I think the Racket documentation overall is very good, I agree that it could use more examples.

Comment: @bravmech If this answered the question that you asked, would you please mark it as accepted? Thank you.